# how to set variable on previous page back to 1

Tags: php

I have some variable where everytime the form is submiited or page is refreshed, it adds 1 to $sessionMinus. But if the user goes onto the previous page and then goes back onto this page, I want $sessionMinus to go back to being '1'.

At the moment if lets say the number is 3 and then the user goes back to previous page and then back to this page, it still displays 3, but I want it to go back to 1. I heard I have to set either $sessionMinus or $_SESSION['sessionCount'] to '1' on the previous page but how do I do this?

below is the code for the current page (not previous page) on how the $sessionMinus is declared and incremented:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['sessionCount'])){
         $_SESSION['sessionCount'] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
         $_SESSION['sessionCount']++;
    }

$sessionMinus =  $_SESSION['sessionCount'];


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the previous page, do:

```
if( isset( $_SESSION['sessionCount'])){
    $_SESSION['sessionCount'] = 1; 
   // Or maybe 0 if you want $sessionMinus = 1 on next page
}
```

Comment: Thank for the answer :) best answer when it lets me mark it in 5 mins